# MultiSelect outline vairant property does not work

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, single-page-application, multi-select

I am working on the select controls for the front end. When I used single select the `variant` property works fine, but when using the `multiselect` component, `variant` property seems not working.

I have tried couple things as I tried give the property directly into the `FormControl` and also within the `Select` Tag but unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried `InputVairant="outlined"` but that also didn't work.

Here is the sample code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3mjzo

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're providing input prop an Input element, which does not support variant. 
Remove that, and you can provide variant to your Select component (also change InputVariant to variant - because InputVariant prop is not supported).

```
 <Select
          multiple
          variant="outlined"
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
 >
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]